# NSDateformatter always retun nil on iPhone model MD269LL but OK on other models

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

I've encontered a problem where NSDateformatter always return nil for all of the NSDate variable below when running on iPhone model MD269LL (so far tested on iOS5.x) but OK on other models with iOS4.3~5.1

```
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatterTime4 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatterTime2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *temp1 = [formatterTime2 dateFromString:@"2012-03-22 22:01:01"];

[formatterTime3 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *temp2 = [formatterTime3 dateFromString:@"2011-03-21 20:35:03 GMT+8"];

[formatterTime4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a zzz"];
NSDate *temp3 = [formatterTime4 dateFromString:@"2011-03-21 9:35 am GMT+8"];

[formatterTime setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
NSDate *temp4 = [formatterTime dateFromString:@"2012-03-17 16:09:02 +0800"];
```

I am very confused with what's wrong with the code. Anybody have a solution?

***EDITED.

Comment: why you are initing formatterTimeX variable, but using formatterPrayerTimeX ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have edited the above. It should be formatterTimeX

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the time settings of your device?

Comment: i don't think its a problem with the setting on the device. since this functions are straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once on one specific device model - or that's what I thought since I had ruled everything else out.  In the end I reset the device completely and when I reinstalled everything it was working again.  Might be worth a shot.